# What is Class<T, String> type in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Using this [Mapbox doc](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/5.1.4/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/layers/PropertyFactory.html) as a reference:

`lineOpacity(Function<T,Float> function)`

> The opacity at which the line will be drawn.

What parameter will `lineOpacity()` accept?

Can someone show me an example of a parameter passed in to this function?

Comment: Can you please match your title with the actual question you're asking?

Comment: `Function<T, Float>` is an example of `<Class<T, String>` @FedericoklezCulloca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static <T> PropertyValue<Function<T,Float>> lineOpacity(Function<T,Float> function)
```

> The opacity at which the line will be drawn.
>
> Type Parameters: T - the function input type
>
> Parameters: function - a wrapper function for Float
>
> Returns: property wrapper around a Float function

This is fully what their documentation state. As stated `Function` class is a wrapper function for Float. `lineOpacity` method will return a `Type T` that will be passed into the `function`

I like to see this as a `HashMap<T,M>` where `T - the key, let's say String` and `M - the value, let's say Integer`

You asked for an example

```
lineOpacity(new Function<String, Float>()) // will return a String
```

Comment: Thankyou. So an example would be `lineOpacity(new Function<String, Float>("semi-opaque", 0.5f))`?